# Why are questions that are migrated away kept in the list?

Tags: discussion

When a question is migrated to another SO forum, why is the original retained with `[migrated]` appended?

Why not migrate and remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are managed by the *system*, which we don't really have any control over.

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work/10250#10250) answer on Stack Exchange's Meta site, migrated questions are  only kept as a "stub" for 30 days after migration and then automatically deleted:

> **The question is left as a stub**, or pathway to the new site, **for 30
>   days**, after which it is automatically deleted. During this time, the
>   stub question will be locked to preserve the post in its original
>   state, preventing comments and votes. (Again, this deletion causes a
>   reversal of all associated reputation on the origin site.) Note that
>   the old link will continue to redirect to the new question even after
>   that time.
>
> When a post is migrated, the destination question will contain a
>   notice saying that it was migrated and contain a link to the old (now
>   stub) question's revision history. This will be publicly visible to
>   <10k users even after the stub is deleted.
>
> This notice is hidden 60 days after the question is migrated, though
>   the entries still remain in the revision history.

There's quite a lot of emphasis on tracking revisions and the history of questions on Stack Exchange, so this was likely added to *system's* functions to aid in that.

Comment: Aha...so it is deleted...eventually.  Kind of makes sense if you know, but it is confusing if you don't.